# How do I add list elements to another list with an order in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a "List" of decimal numbers and a "Blank_list". I would like the List members to be added to the Blank-lists in the following order:
1. The index of each element in the list that is between two integers is added to the lower integer of the Blank-list.
2. If two elements of the list were in the same interval, the priority is with an element whose decimal point is larger.
For example, elements 1.23, 1.59 and 1.56 are between two integers 1 and 2. Then their index is added to the first list of Blank-list.  Also, since the 1.59 is greater than 1.56 and greater than 1.23, the order of their indexes is: [6, 3, 8]
I want Output, but if you run the following code, Wrong_Output is shown.

```
List = [1.23, 2.46, 4.85, 0.76, 1.59, 1.56, 0.84, 2.12, 0.1]
Blank_list = [[], [], [], [], []]
Output = [[6, 3, 8], [4, 5, 0], [1, 7], [], [2]]
Wrong_Output = [[8, 6, 3], [5, 0, 4], [1, 7], [], [2]]

for index in range(0, len(List)):
    for sub in range(0, 5):
        if sub < List[index] < sub + 1:
            max_num = List[index-1]
            if List[index] < max_num:
                Blank_list[sub].insert(0, index)
            else:
                Blank_list[sub].append(index)
print(Blank_list)
```

Comment: Your explanation would be much clearer with simple, concrete examples to illustrate your rules.

Comment: " If two elements of the list were in the same interval, the priority is with an element whose decimal point is larger" => then the first sublist in `Òutput` should be `[8, 3, 6]` not `[6, 3, 8]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your specs, `output[0]` should be `[8, 3, 6]` - the matching values being (respectively) `[0.1, 0.76, 0.84]`.

Assuming the output example is wrong and the spec is correct, the simplest way is to sort the sublists after they are filled. You can do this using the `key` argument to `list.sort()`:

```
source = [1.23, 2.46, 4.85, 0.76, 1.59, 1.56, 0.84, 2.12, 0.1]
results = [[], [], [], [], []]

for index, value in enumerate(source):
    results[int(value)].append(index)

for sub in results:
    sub.sort(key=lambda index: source[index])

print(results)
```